# Rendering 2D Text in OpenGL in the modern pipeline

Tags: java, opengl, text, lwjgl, text-rendering

I've been searching the internet for quite some time and I have not been able to find satisfying content, I am using Java/LWJGL/OpenGL to create a 3D application.
I am running it on 3.3 on the core profile, because I want to have absolutely **nothing** to do with legacy OpenGL.

However I cannot find any small jar that allows me to render 2D text.
If I need to do it all by myself, then well... Fine. But I was not intending to invest so much time in something so trivial as printing some 2D text on the screen.

What I have come accross so far:

- Slick-Util library for Java, relies on the legacy OpenGL.
- Some proprietary class called `TextRender` that has somethign to do with Java2D, seems quite sketchy and almost sounds to me like it will create it's own OpenGL context and I want to manage those things.

What else is there out there to render 2D text? Do I really need to make something myself for something such trivial?
I just wanted to output the frames per second.

Comment: you can use FreeType to rasterize text